# Set a custom serializer in the include file with rails 5

Tags: ruby, serialization, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I have this code that brings one vacancy from my model Vacancy and then render in json the attributes according to the serializer VacancyDetailSerializer:

> Controller

```
vacancy = Vacancy.find(params[:id])    
render json: vacancy, serializer: VacancyDetailSerializer, 
                      include: [:restaurant]
```

The thing here is that in the `include: [:restaurant]` I want to specify a custom serializer the way I did with vacancy, because right now is taking the serializer of RestaurantSerializer, but I don't want to take that file, **is there a way to do it with the include?** Maybe is here in the controller, or maybe in the serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `belongs_to :restaurant` association in the `VacancyDetailSerializer`, then `serializer` for this association can be [specified](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md#belongs_to):

```
class VacancyDetailSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :restaurant, serializer: AnotherRestaurantSerializer
end
```

Or it can be overridden by providing a block:

```
class VacancyDetailSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :restaurant do
    AnotherRestaurantSerializer.new(object.restaurant)
  end
end
```

Or a custom [association serializer lookup](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md#overriding-association-serializer-lookup) can be implemented.